# Riod-iOS Error: You don't have write permissions "Gem::FilePermissionError"

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have downloaded a [Riot-iOS](https://github.com/vector-im/riot-ios) and follow a build instructions.

When I run '*$ bundle install*'

> Traceback (most recent call last):    2: from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in
>   `<main>'  1: from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in`
>   activate_bin_path'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in
>   `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.2) required by your
>   /Users/premkumar/Downloads/riot-ios-develop/Gemfile.lock.
>   (Gem::GemNotFoundException) To update to the latest version installed
>   on your system, run`bundle update --bundler`. To install the missing
>   version, run`gem install bundler:2.0.2`

After I run a '*$ bundle exec pod install*'

> Traceback (most recent call last):    2: from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in
>   `<main>'  1: from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in`
>   activate_bin_path'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in
>   `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.2) required by your
>   /Users/premkumar/Downloads/riot-ios-develop/Gemfile.lock.
>   (Gem::GemNotFoundException) To update to the latest version installed
>   on your system, run`bundle update --bundler`. To install the missing
>   version, run`gem install bundler:2.0.2`

So, I update a gem by running '*$gem update --system*'

> Updating rubygems-update ERROR:  While executing gem ...
>   (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

[image]

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you are using the system Ruby that ships with MacOS. In order for this to work you would need to try running these commands with `sudo`.  You can also try installing Ruby with RVM(https://rvm.io/) then running those same commands without `sudo`

RVM makes it very easy. Run this from your terminal:

```sh
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

This command will install RVM and the latest stable Ruby version now 2.6.3.

Comment: @KathiresanMurugan Please see the updated answer with the needed commands.

Comment: I run that curl command. But I received this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlB3V.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to stress a point that [@ZachTuttle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57010250/5783745) makes: you're using the system installation of ruby (!!) (the one that comes preinstalled with macOS) - 99.9% of the time you **don't** want to do that!

You can tell this is happening because throughout the error messages are references to the location of the macOS system installation:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions ...
```

To fix, you almost certainly want to get the output of `ruby -v` to be one that you installed yourself. There are a number of [recommended ways](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/) to install ruby.

If you have already installed ruby yourself (i.e. a non-system version), you just have to figure out how to get rails/bundle/related processes to use your installed version of ruby, rather than the system installation. That will differ depending on the way you installed it.

As an example, I was getting similar error messages, and happened to be using the rbenv ruby package manager, so I had to make rbenv use ruby installed via rbenv, rather than the system installation (to do that, I ran `rbenv versions` to show the installed versions, then `rbenv global 3.0.3` to switch to one of the self-installed versions). What you have to do may be completely different, depending on how you installed ruby, but ultimately you almost certainly want to get rails/bundler to use your self-installed ruby, rather than the system installation which it's currently trying to use.