# error when create a new folder by rails command : "can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am newbie with Rails and here is my problem.

I created a new Rails's folder by this command

`rails new freelancer --database=postgresql --javascript=webpack`

And it gave me this error :

`can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException) from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in` activate_bin_path'
from /Users/xxx/.gem/ruby/3.1.2/bin/rails:25:in `<main>' from /Users/xxx/.gem/ruby/3.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in` eval'
from /Users/xxx/.gem/ruby/3.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'`

When I checked my ruby version, it gave me this :

`ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958)`

When I checked my rails version by the command rails -v, it still show me this error :

`can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)`

So I thought that maybe my problem is because of my rails's version it up to date, maybe I must reinstall rails ?

What should I do ? Could you please give me some advices ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error is railties not installed in your pc. Or your Rube setup is not properly.

Now Try it: install railties gem `gem install railties`

Than you can crate your new rails application again.

Answer (score 0):

From this line of the error message

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6
```

it's saying the ruby version being used is the system installation (that is, the installation that comes with macOS). You almost certainly don't want that.

Try installing ruby using one of the recommended ways.

In my case I'd already installed ruby via the package manager, rbenv.

But `ruby -v` still referred to the system library (it gave `ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]`, which isn't one I installed myself), so I changed it with `rbenv versions` (to see which versions were installed; you can install a new version with `rbenv install x.x.x`) and then `rbenv global x.x.x` to set the ruby version. But the method to use will differ depending on how you install ruby. I wrote a longer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75453553/5783745). Hope it helps.